# Tensorflow 2.1.0 - No attribute named ' app '

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

My Tensorflow Version: 2.1.0

My Python Version: 3.7.0

Hi I'm following this tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYqvx_DM45U)

I'm at the stage where I need to generate a TFRecord.

However the tensorflow version he is using in the video is older than mine and it throws me an error saying there isn't an attribute named app.

I tried using `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`

and changing the `tf.app.run()` to `tf.compat.v1.app.run()`

But this only throws me an error saying

```
Taceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 106, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\otter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\otter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\otter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 97, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 86, in create_tf_example
    'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
  File "C:\Users\otter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\dataset_util.py", line 26, in int64_list_feature
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
TypeError: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: int, long
```

I'm not sure what's going on e_e

Here is the python script I'm using to generate the TFRecord

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to the image directory')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'C':
        return 1
    elif row_label == 'CH':
        return 2
    elif row_label == 'T':
        return 3
    elif row_label == 'TH':
        return 4
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

**UPDATE 1**
I added `tf.disable_v2_behavior()` and managed to get 2 files created after running the code, train and test.record

And this error

```
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 99, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\otter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\otter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\otter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 90, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 79, in create_tf_example
    'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
  File "C:\Users\otter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\dataset_util.py", line 26, in int64_list_feature
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
TypeError: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: int, long
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `tf.compat.v1.app.run()` is even half-working at all. If you've imported `tensorflow.compat.v1` as `tf`, then the statement `tf.compat.v1.app.run()` is roughly equivalent to `tensorflow.compat.v1.compat.v1.app.run()` (with `compat.v1` appearing *twice*). Try just using `tf.app.run()` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install TF 1.x to run this example.

Comment: Importing `tensorflow.compat.v1` as `tf` should effectively use the old 1.x API of Tensorflow. That's what `compat.v1` is for.

Comment: Sorry. Have you use tf.disable_v2_behavior() ?https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Comment: @jbasquiat Oh :) It's much better now but it still throws me an error. I have updated the error in my question. It now generates the .record files but it's 0Kb

Comment: Your variable classes is None in some point and it should be always an integer. I guess when you set it to None in class_text_to_int function you should be set it to 0.